# SharedPreference saving just one value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I'm trying to make favorites module in my app. If user click favorite button for a radio, this radio must displayed in Favorites screen. But just last clicked radio shown in Favorites screen. I want to save more than one radios in Favorites. Where I'm doing wrong? thanks in advance.

**This is favorite button in RadioFragment**

```
add_favorites_button= (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add_favorites_button);
        add_favorites_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putString("radio_link", radio_play_link);
                editor.putString("radio_namee", radio_name);
                editor.commit();
            }
        });
```

**And I'm trying to get these values and put in ArrayList in FavoritesFragment. To display received values, I sent them in textview to try.**

```
public class FavoritesFragment extends Fragment {

    public FavoritesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    TextView radio_name_txt, radio_link_txt;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view=  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorites, container, false);

        List<String> radio_name_list = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> radio_link_list = new ArrayList<>();
        SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFS",0);
        radio_name_list.add(settings.getString("radio_namee", ""));
        radio_link_list.add(settings.getString("radio_link", ""));


        radio_name_txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.radio_name_txt);
        radio_link_txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.radio_link_txt);
        String a= "";
        String b= "";

        for (int i =0; i<radio_name_list.size(); i++) {
            a = a +radio_name_list.get(i);
            b = b +radio_link_list.get(i);
        }

        radio_name_txt.setText(a);
        radio_link_txt.setText(b);

        return view;
    }


}
```

Comment: Have you got 7000 keys? I advice you to use SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of data and Shared Preferences is not the write option to store your data for 7000 items. Shared preference is good for easy and less frequent data storage, For your case you need to make a SQLite Database. If its totally new to your then pay a visit in Androids only Documentation Training in [this link.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

Answer (score 1):

since you are using same key for every radio button insert it will overwrite the previous values.

You need to store values in an array and then store array in the preferneces.

Or the better way is to use sqllite database in the android to store the likes in a table.

Comment: I have more than 7000 radio links and names.  you mean I need to write all this values in array? I'm new on Android, can you explain it on my code please?

Answer (score 1):

Try displaying the values from the Lists radio_name_list and radio_link_list in a ListView:

- Save the values in an Array List.
- Create a ListView instead of a TextView.
- Create an ArrayAdapter and set it as the adapter for your ListView.

As far as I can see you only have one TextView. Try creating a ListView instead of a TextView. It will be more organized.

Answer (score 1):

> editor.putString("radio_link", radio_play_link); 
>   editor.putString("radio_namee", radio_name);

You are overwriting the favorite every time you try to add a new one, so instead of doing the above, do this:

```
editor.putString(radio_play_link, radio_play_link);
editor.putString(radio_name, radio_name);
```

So now you have a key-value pair, and you can iterate over your favorites like this:

```
String radioLink = "", radioKey = "";    
for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : getSharedPreferences("PREFS",0).getAll().entrySet()) {
        radioKey = entry.getKey();
        radioLink = (String) entry.getValue();         
}
```

Comment: Finally, I used your way. Thanks!